# Need help in filtering and expanding searching results

Tags: interaction-design, filter, search-results

The image attached is a search results page with filters. The current image shows three filters (Category, Price and Brand) and the corresponding selection check boxes. Consider the following example. If I need search results for hammer of category Cat1 and price Price1, I would have to select the check boxes of Cat1 and Price1. This is straightforward. Now how should I modify the  filter/expand column if I need search results for the following: hammer of category Cat1 with price Price1 and further expand this search results with all hammers of price Price2?

[image: Search results]

Comment: "further expand this search results" do you mean two different searches?

Comment: No it a single search. 
Step1: I select 2 options(Cat1 and Price1) -> This narrows down the results and shows hammers of category1 with price1.

Step2: I want to update the previous results with one more option (price2)? (I need to display all hammers of price2 irrespective of the brand and category along with the Step1 results).  How do I design the side bar to accomodate filtering and expanding of results?

Answer (score 1):

I think your example here is too vague to understand, I mean a real world example or the actual use-case of your problem would help.

let's take an e-commerce site example, which would have something like below.

[image]

Here as per your example we have selected **category** : Men and **price-range** : 500-999 bucks. so if you select **price-range 2** which is 1000-1999 bucks usually it filters and shows winter jackets for **category** men and in both **price-ranges** which makes sense.

according to your example if I filter then I would get winter jackets of **category** women for **price-range 2** with all **brands** appear which is weird since user already filtered down **category** as men. so showing him results from women category totally fails the filter system.

I would suggest come with the real data if possible for your question. then It would be easier to answer. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, when the user selects several checkboxes from the same Top-filter it adds, but when the user selects from several Top-filter it reduces.

For example:

```
Total items 1400

Cat1 1000
Cat2 400

Price1 700
Price2 500
Price3 200

Brand1 1300
Brand2 100
```

- Selecting Cat1 + Cat2 would display all 1400 items.
- Selecting Cat1 + Price1 would display 600 (from those Cat1 1000 items 600 have Price1, 300 Price2, 100 Price3)

---

So what you are trying to do is not:

- Cat1 + Price1 + Price2

but:

- (Cat1 + Price1) + (Cat1 + Cat2 + Price2)

So **those parenthesis mean two different filtered queries from all the items**.

The only way I can think of as you have it right now is to add a second filtered query.

Something like:

```
Show:
 • Items from |Cat1| and |Price1|
 • Items from |All categories| and |Price2|
```

But it gets a bit complex so better to stick to one query at a time.